# Does $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ imply $X,Y$ independent? What about $E(XYZ)=E(X)E(Y)E(Z)$

Tags: probability

We know that the converse is true. But are they sufficient to prove independence? Are there any counter examples?

Answer (score 2):

No, the usual counterexample is $X$ having symmetric distribution and $Y = X^2$. To show independence the equality you wrote would have to hold for every bounded function of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

For the three variables version: let's say you have a die with three sides (call them $a, b, c$). After you roll the die, define three random variables based on the outcome in this way:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
& a & b & c \\ \hline
X & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
Y & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
Z & 1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}$$

Note that:

- No matter what you roll, the product $XYZ$ is $0$.
- $\mathbb E X = \mathbb E Y = \mathbb E Z = 0.$
- And yet, $X, Y, Z$ are clearly dependent. (For instance, if you tell me that $Y = 0$, then I know with certainty what $X$ and $Z$ are.)

You could do something similar for 4 variables, 5 variables, etc.